# Android detect when the app is killed by the user

Tags: android

I was wondering if there is a way to detect when the app is being killed by the user, meaning the user intentionally killed the app. I basically need to distinguish between the user killing the app and other types such as OS claimed memory, device restarted, the app crashed, and so on.

Comment: OnDestory method of android life cycle can detect killed app for device restart you need to use brodcast reciever to listen system events

Comment: Android just released a new API for exactly what you are describing: ApplicationExitInfo, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ApplicationExitInfo

Comment: @TechRando thank you, seems like that is exactly what I am looking for. Any ideas on how to use this? Not sure how to access this after reading the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you have to use the ActivityManager class and the .getHistoricalProcessExitReasons method. Here's some more info from the docs: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/features#app-process-exit-reasons

Comment: @TechRando finally managed to make it work but unfortunately, this is not usable for me. Seems like the call requires API 30 and above which eliminates a lot of devices out there... Thanks tho, will for sure use this in the future where it is appropriate to set the minimum API level to 30.